# How to write data to excel using threads

Tags: java, multithreading, apache-poi

**Requirement**

I have a program, which generates a lots of data during the execution. I need to write the generated data to excel file, but this makes the execution slower. So I decided to use `thread`. My expectation is that main thread execute the program and generate the data. Whenever data is generated a new thread is created and the thread needs to write the data to excel in background. Only one thread is allowed to write data to excel at a time.

**What I tried**

```
public class ExcelWriter implements TestDataWriter, Runnable{
        String testCase;
        String columnName;
        Object data;
        WriteOperations write;
        public ExcelWriter(String testCase,String columnName,Object data){
            this.testCase = testCase;
            this.columnName = columnName;
            this.data = data;
            write = new WriteOperations();
        }

        public void run(){
            write.public void setColumnData(String testCase,String columnName,Object data);
        }
    }
```

and the setColumnData() method looks like

```
public class WriteOperations {  
    public void setColumnData(String testCase,String columnName,Object data) {
        synchronized (WriteOperations.class) {
                // logic to write data to excel
            }
        }
    }
```

and finally I call the methods like

```
TestDataWriter dataWriter = new ExcelWriter("TC01_04", "URL", "http://www.selenium.hq", excelData);
Thread thread1 = new Thread((ExcelWriter)dataWriter);
thread1.start();
dataWriter = new ExcelWriter("TC01_05", "URL", "http://www.google.com", excelData);
Thread thread2 = new Thread((ExcelWriter)dataWriter);
thread2.start();
```

**What issue I faced**

Some times the excel file got corrupted. Some times, data is written partially (some threads write data, some dont)

Any thoughts?

Comment: if i had to take a guess your program ends before you threads do.
consider using a thread pool, and shutting down the thread pool forces a wait until they all finish (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/thread-pools-java/)

Comment: Many threads writing one at a time to an Excel file can't be faster than a single thread writing sequentially to an Excel file.

Comment: I agree with @JBN, if you're going to keep using threads to do the work, why not have them write their data into some other object (maybe `StringBuffer`, notice Im not using `StringBuilder`) , then once all the threads are done, write that object out with the main thread.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the [edit] link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Comment: Thought: we can't tell you what is wrong with your code when you are not sharing it here. On the other hand, most likely, you got plenty of complicated code. So the real answer is probably that you learn how to debug your code. Beyond that: start by avoiding to create raw threads. Thread about ExecutorServices, and Futures and such things. We have much better abstractions for such work in 2018. Dont use the stuff that is 20 years old!

Comment: were you able to solve this problem? I have similar problem.